# What's wrong with my Python 3.x program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written all of the mathematical functions in Python, but can't get the program to go to the correct option when prompted by the user

```
print ("""Calculations Menu:
    1) Area (Square)
    2) Area (Rectangle)
    3) Area (Circle)
    4) Perimeter (Square)
    5) Perimeter (Rectangle)
    6) Perimeter (Circle)
    7) Exit
""")

choice = input("Input Menu Choice (1,2,3,4,5,6 or 7)?\n")

if choice == "1":
    print ("You have chosen Area (Square)")

    def area_square (width, height):
        return width * height

    def positive_input (prompt):
        number = float(input(prompt))
        while number <=0:
            print ("Must be a positive number.")
            number = float(input(prompt))
        return number

    w = positive_input ("Width: ")
    h = positive_input ("Height: ")

    print ("Width = ", w, "Height = ", h, "So Area =", area_square(w, h))

if choice == "2":
    print ("You have chosen Area (Rectangle)")

    def area_rectangle (width, height):
        return width * height

    def positive_input (prompt):
        number = float(input(prompt))
        while number <=0:
            print ("Must be a positive number.")
            number = float(input(prompt))
        return number

    w = positive_input ("Width: ")
    h = positive_input ("Height: ")

    print ("Width = ", w, "Height = ", h, "So Area =", area_rectangle(w, h))

if choice == "3":
    print ("You have chosen Area (Circle)")

    def area_circle (radius, pi):
        return radius**2 * pi

    def positive_input (prompt):
        number = float(input(prompt))
        while number <=0:
            print ("Must be a positive number.")
            number = float(input(prompt))
        return number

    radius = positive_input ("radius: ")
    pi = 3.14159265

    print ("Radius = ", radius, "Pi = ", pi, "So Area =", area_circle(radius, pi))

if choice == "4":
    print ("You have chosen Perimeter (Square)")

    def perimeter_square (side, ):
        return side * 4

    def positive_input (prompt):
        number = float(input(prompt))
        while number <=0:
            print ("Must be a positive number.")
            number = float(input(prompt))
        return number

    side = positive_input ("side: ")

    print ("side = ", "So Perimeter =", perimeter_square(side,))

if choice == "5":
    print ("You have chosen Perimeter (Rectangle)")

    def perimeter_rectangle (sideA, sideB,):
        return (sideA + sideB) * 2

    def positive_input (prompt):
        number = float(input(prompt))
        while number <=0:
            print ("Must be a positive number.")
            number = float(input(prompt))
        return number

    sideA = positive_input ("Length: ")
    sideB = positive_input ("Width: ")

    print ("Length = ", sideA, "Width =  ", sideB, "So Perimeter =", perimeter_rectangle(sideA, sideB))

if choice == "6":
    print ("You have chosen Perimeter (Circle)")

    def perimeter_circle (diameter, pi):
        return diameter * pi

    def positive_input (prompt):
        number = float(input(prompt))
        while number <=0:
            print ("Must be a positive number.")
            number = float(input(prompt))
        return number

    diameter = positive_input ("Diameter: ")
    pi = 3.14159265

    print ("Diameter = ", diameter, "Pi =  ", pi, "So Perimeter =", perimeter_circle(diameter, pi))
```

Comment: Please format your code and clarify your question.

Comment: we're a bit confused here; can you please tell us how you execute your script? Are you intending to use python 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: @Fred: The question was tagged `python-3.x` from the get-go.

Comment: After attempting to fix the indentation of your code, it now looks like basically it would work -- so perhaps improper formatting was the main cause of your problem...

Answer (score 4):

When I run your code, it works just fine, except of course that it goes through all 7 possibilities instead of just the one you selected.

(Note that if you run this code with a Python 2.x interpreter instead of 3.x, it will appear to work, but never do anything. That's because in 2.x, `input` evaluates its input, so `choice` will be, e.g., the int `3` instead of the string `"3"`. But if you run it with a Python 3 interpreter as intended, that's not a problem.)

The reason it does this is just indentation. You've got code that's only supposed to run for a given choice, but it's not indented under the right `if` block. Once you fix that, everything is fine.

Since it's silly to define the exact same `positive_input` function 6 times, I moved that part out to the top. Otherwise, the only change I made was indentation:

```
def positive_input (prompt):
    number = float(input(prompt))
    while number <=0:
        print ("Must be a positive number.")
        number = float(input(prompt))
    return number

print ("""Calculations Menu:
    1) Area (Square)
    2) Area (Rectangle)
    3) Area (Circle)
    4) Perimeter (Square)
    5) Perimeter (Rectangle)
    6) Perimeter (Circle)
    7) Exit
    """)

choice = input("Input Menu Choice (1,2,3,4,5,6 or 7)?\n")

if choice == "1":
    print ("You have chosen Area (Square)")

    def area_square (width, height):
        return width * height

    w = positive_input ("Width: ")
    h = positive_input ("Height: ")

    print ("Width = ", w, "Height = ", h, "So Area =", area_square(w, h))

if choice == "2":
    print ("You have chosen Area (Rectangle)")

    def area_rectangle (width, height):
        return width * height

    w = positive_input ("Width: ")
    h = positive_input ("Height: ")

    print ("Width = ", w, "Height = ", h, "So Area =", area_rectangle(w, h))

if choice == "3":
    print ("You have chosen Area (Circle)")

    def area_circle (radius, pi):
        return radius**2 * pi

    radius = positive_input ("radius: ")
    pi = 3.14159265

    print ("Radius = ", radius, "Pi = ", pi, "So Area =", area_circle(radius, pi))

if choice == "4":
    print ("You have chosen Perimeter (Square)")

    def perimeter_square (side, ):
        return side * 4

    side = positive_input ("side: ")

    print ("side = ", "So Perimeter =", perimeter_square(side,))

if choice == "5":
    print ("You have chosen Perimeter (Rectangle)")

    def perimeter_rectangle (sideA, sideB,):
        return (sideA + sideB) * 2

    sideA = positive_input ("Length: ")
    sideB = positive_input ("Width: ")

    print ("Length = ", sideA, "Width =  ", sideB, "So Perimeter =", perimeter_rectangle(sideA, sideB))

if choice == "6":
    print ("You have chosen Perimeter (Circle)")

    def perimeter_circle (diameter, pi):
        return diameter * pi

    diameter = positive_input ("Diameter: ")
    pi = 3.14159265

    print ("Diameter = ", diameter, "Pi =  ", pi, "So Perimeter =", perimeter_circle(diameter, pi))
```

---

While we're at it, a few other changes I'd probably make (mostly minor):

First, [Python style](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) strongly discourages putting spaces before the parentheses for a function call.

Next, you can use `math.pi` to get `pi` to the right precision for your Python build's `float` type, instead of having to type in your own approximation and guess at the precision.

If you're chaining together a bunch of mutually-exclusive `if` statements, using `elif` makes it clear to the reader that they're supposed to be mutually exclusive.

You might want to consider going farther and moving each choice into a function, so you can just do this:

```
if choice == "1":
    do_area_square()
elif choice == "2":
    do_area_rectangle()
# ...
```

… or even:

```
functions = {"1": do_area_square, "2": do_area_rectangle, # ...
functions[choice]()
```

… or:

```
functions = [do_area_square, do_area_rectangle, ...]
functions[int(choice)-1]()
```

Comment: [+1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16285960/297323)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will cast some light on your problem:

```
In [6]: choice = input("Input Menu Choice (1,2,3,4,5,6 or 7)?\n")
Input Menu Choice (1,2,3,4,5,6 or 7)?
1

In [7]: type(choice)
Out[7]: int

In [9]: choice == "1"
Out[9]: False

In [10]: choice == 1
Out[10]: True
```

Comment: Wait, if he's in Python 3.x, this whole answer is wrong, because `input` will return a string, not an int. And if he's in 2.x, the actual problem is that… he's writing 3.x code and running it in 2.x.

Comment: oh whoops he is in python 3.x so input == raw_input(2.x), also he is getting a string in 3x :/

Comment: @abarnert - you are right! Considering to delete this answer. I'll wait some more to see if additional info from OP shows up

Comment: @FredrikPihl: After fixing his indentation, it works in 3.x, but does exactly what you'd expect in 2.x, so… it's possible that the problem _is_ that he's writing 3.x code and running in 2.x, in which case this answer (mostly) explains why that doesn't work. So yeah, I think you should wait and see if he gives more info.